# How can I manage classes like "row" and "span(X)" of Twitter Bootstrap to work on @media print?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, printing-web-page

I need to print web pages in my website and I'm wondering how to make `row` and `spanX` classes of Bootstrap work so I can easily manage the content of the printed page.

**For example:**

`<div class="row-fluid">`
`<div class="span12">`
`<strong>Some stuff</strong>`
`</div>`
`</div>`

and

`<div class="row-fluid">`
`<div class="span6 offset6">`
`<strong>Some stuff</strong>`
`</div>`
`</div>`

look exactly the same when calling `window.print()`.

In the example above, `<strong>Some stuff</strong>` is not being pushed ahead by the `offset6`.

**I've done 2 things:**

- Taken all `@media print` code from `bootstrap.css` and
  `bootstrapresponsive.css`;
- Changed `media` to `all`:
   from `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="/path/css/bstrapmin.css" media="screen" />` 
   
  to `<link
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/css/bstrapmin.css"
  media="all" />`;

With these changes, header, footer and the bootstrap (original) font have appeared on the printed page but still no effect from/of the classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a separate stylesheet and place it after all other stylesheets and do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/css/print-stylesheet.css" media="print" />
```

Anything you put in there will override any other styles you have in your media="screen" stylesheets. Just make sure it is the last CSS file called in your DOM.

I forget if you have to include **@media print** in your print style sheet, I think the **media="print"** will take care of that

Comment: Thank you but I don't think your answer solves my question. Read it again, please.

Comment: What are all of the CSS files are you calling into your files? Just "bstrapmin.css" (which I assume you have customized to fit your needs?)?

Also, is this a problem with the positioning of items or the font styling of items? The line where you said " the bootstrap (original) font have appeared on the printed page " is what I think is throwing me off.

Comment: None of my CSS files are overriding bootstrap classes. My point is if the fonts of bootstrap css are working, why do row and span aren't working?

Comment: I see. Well I wish you luck in finding your answer! The only thing that may help is making sure your @print media query is at the very bottom of the file or move all that into a media="print" link...or try to make a completely separate **test** file with only print CSS styles (nothing else) to test out those classes behaviors with no other styles to get in the way and override. Maybe it's a Bootstrap issue if you still can't get those to look right. Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I solved my problem without using bootstrap classes. I used margin and padding to manage the content in the pages.